# Swift unexpectedly found nil when there is actual value

Tags: swift

I have following code:

```
class User {

    var listsDict : [String : List]!

    func addList (list : List) -> Void {
        print(list.name)
        listsDict[list.name] = list
    }

    func listForName (name: String) -> List? {
        return listsDict[name]
    }

}


class List {

    let name : String
    var movies : Set<String>

    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
        movies = Set<String>()
    }

    func printList (){
        print(movies)
    }

}

var list = List(name: "List")
list.movies = Set<String>(["LOTR", "SAW", "POC"])
list.printList()


var johny = User()
johny.addList(list: list)
```

When i call `johny.addList(list: list)` i got an error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But there is a value. I created instance of list previously and even print in log name of list (and it successfully printed). Why i got an error?

Comment: The error comes from `listsDict` which is `nil`. You should initialize `listsDict` in`User`. BTW,: "List" is a bad name for a set. ;)

Comment: change from var listsDict : [String : List]! to   var listsDict : [String : List] = [:]

Comment: @macmoonshine oh.. sorry )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `listsDict` is declared as implicit unwrapped optional but **not** initialized.

Instead of using an implicit unwrapped optional property initialize the dictionary non-optional

```
var listsDict = [String : List]()
```

Comment: is () is equal to [Object new]; in Obj-c?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever assign a value to User.listsDict, thus it's nil when you try to add a value to it.  Just part of the reason ! should never be used unless you absolutely have to.  And in this case, you don't.

```
var listsDict : [String : List]!
```

Should be

```
var listsDict = [String : List]()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because of `listsDict[list.name] = list` in the method:

```
func addList (list : List) -> Void {
        print(list.name)
        listsDict[list.name] = list
}
```

You declared it as:

```
var listsDict : [String : List]!
```

Appending to a dictionary without initialize it should cause this error, You should initialize it first (`var listsDict = [String : List]()`) and I would suggest to declare it as *lazy* variable:

```
lazy var listsDict = [String : List]()
```

and your code should works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I found this try of error. I just do this below steps

Just `print("variable name")` .

then I use

```
if <variable name> != nil {

}else{

}
```

This is my way of handling these type of errors.

Comment: You should use conditional binding instead (`if let ...`, `guard let ...`). It's rare to need to check if a variable is `nil`, without then needing to use the variable